# Pass specific TouchEvent to specific view

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have 2 `onTouchListeners()` :

```
 child.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {           
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // DO STUFF
                    return true;
                }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // DO STUFF
                    return true;
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                   //pass this event to parent
                }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

and my parent `onTouchListener()` is just the normal implementation. I want to pass the Move-event to the parent's `onTouchListener()`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to pass the touch event to the parent, just return false from that code path. For your requirement, return false if the action is ACTION_MOVE.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. (Now return false is in the ACTION_MOVE segment). But when I touch the child and move, nothing happens. The child is an ImageView-maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Now you have to handle that event in your parent's onTouchListener. If you have already handled it, make sure the event is passed to the parent. Make a log there and see if the move event is being passed.

Comment: it's still not passing.

Comment: It's a RelativeLayout. When I tab on the area of the ImageView - the ACTION_DOWN is called. analog with ACTION_UP. When I tab on the ImageView and move my finger along the screen: this ACTION_MOVE should be passed right?

Comment: Yes it should be passed.

Comment: meanwhile i fixed it, like you said.